# Ruby "gets" does not wait for user input

Tags: ruby

This is a very silly question, but it doesn't work for me.

I am trying to make the program wait for my input. I tried replacing `gets` with `stdin.gets`, and `$stdin.gets` and when I try `gets.chomp` I get a nil class exception.

```
puts "Get works here?"
option = gets
puts option
```

Comment: How are you running that code?

Answer (score 2):

To work this,you need to call your .rb file from your command prompt. Like say you save your code in a file called `test.rb`.

**test.rb**

```
puts "Get works here?"
option = gets
puts option
```

Then run from your command prompt:

```
C:\Users\arup> ruby test.rb
```

Comment: I directly build using Sublime Text editor, isn't it still supposed to work?

Comment: @RohanDalvi No.. What I said,do that way. I caught your point,as earlier the same happened with me also. :) while your are using `#gets` you need to run the same from command prompt.

Comment: Do you have any explanation for this odd condition?

Answer (score 1):

my script was also not waiting for input from gets(), but started to do so when I used

```rb
$stdin.gets("\n")
```